# Linear independence is hereditary

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

If we have a set of functions $f_i\quad, i\in\mathbb{N}$, then is it true that if $f_i$ is linearly independent on an interval $J$ then, it is also linearly independent on $I$ where  $I\subseteq J$? Is the reverse statement also true?

I think the answer is yes. But I saw somewhere that the result is not true. Any counterexamples? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first assertion is not true. Let $I\subset J, I\not =J$. Take any functions $g_i\colon J\setminus I\to \Bbb R$ which are linearly indepedent and define $ f_i\colon J\to\Bbb R$ by $f_i(x):=g_i(x)$ for $x\in J\setminus 
I$ and by $f_i(x):=0$ for $x\in I$. Then the $ f_i$ are linearly independent as functions defined on $J$ but
dependent as functions defined on $I$.

The reverse statement however is true (and used above). Let the functions $ h_i\colon J\to\Bbb R$ be given, which are linearly independent when restricted to $I$. Let moreover $\sum_i \lambda_ih_i(x)=0$ for all $x\in J$. Then this is also true for all $x\in I$. But then, by assumption, all $\lambda_i=0$ implying that the $ h_i$ are linearly independent as functions defined on $J$.